# YUI, Selenium, Ruby(non rails), Capybara Code Examples

Tags: ruby, selenium, yui, capybara

Are there any Selenium code examples that interact with a page using Yui for display options in plain Ruby code for interacting with the browser running Yui embedded in the HTML?

I have a bunch of user acceptance tests written in Gherkin(Cucumber) which use Capybara to driver these tests in Internet explorer, the tests always fail when interacting with the sub-menu options, ie, sub menus can't be interacted with.

Example:
Main Menu > Sub Menu

The tests come up with a Element not visible no method error, even when the main menu item is selected, therefore exposing the sub menu items, Selenium complains and says the sub menu elements are not visible.

This only happens in I.E. but I have no choice but to use I.E. as that's the browser the business officially supports.

I noticed that there's quite a bit of Yui code in the HTML and began to wonder if there's a driver that can be used with Ruby (pure NOT rails) with my framework, to interact with the Yui driven menu items.

Any suggestions would be cool.

HTML and Java here:

http://pastie.org/2238768

Cucumber feature here:

http://pastie.org/2242279

Ruby step here:

http://pastie.org/2242271

Error log stack trace here:

http://pastie.org/2242316

Thanks,

Loga

Comment: Please can you create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) of this problem. We need to see the HTML and JavaScript for the menu, the cucumber feature that is causing problems, the Ruby step implementation and the extract from the error log in order to help :-)

Comment: @andyb I've added the HTML, Java, Cucumber and Ruby steps to my original question. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, I'll see what I can do. Which version of IE are you seeing the problem with and which version of Firefox is the code working in?